# Chessboard four-colour theorem

Tags: recreational-mathematics, chessboard

Divide the infinite chess-board into countries, where squares in the same country are connected by edges.
Suppose two countries are adjacent if they touch either along an edge or at a corner.
What is the version of the four-colour theorem for this?

Comment: It looks like it's a six-color theorem (at least for any finite board). A quick proof would be to draw circles around each corner and make those countries as well. Then this reduces to the four-color theorem. After coloring the board that way, you can "correct" the colors of countries that co-border the corner countries. You would need at most 2 extra colors to do this.

Comment: Is that because of Kempe chains?  You need at least five colours, as you can have a 2x2 square in an ocean, with the square divided into four 1x1 countries.

Comment: I don't know anything about Kempe chains, so I can't say if it's related or not. I was thinking of a way that the problem could be reduced to the four-color theorem; removing the corners works. Six colors are definitely needed at a minimum. Consider the 2x2 square with "horseshoe" shapes above and below. These are six areas that all border one another.

Comment: If I've got the name right, strings of countries that alternate red/yellow/red/yellow.

Comment: I suppose that's related then. I would give a more formal proof, but I don't think I have the time to do it. Plus I would think illustrations might be helpful. Hopefully this gives you some ideas on how to construct a proof.